# Scala recursive function/method - seeking definitive answer on what this is

Tags: scala, function, recursion, methods

I know the function vs. method discussions are well beat up on, so I will try to be brief.  I am looking to show a tiny block of code and get feedback on:

1. Is it a method, function, both, or something else?
2. If it be a method, can it be made into a function?  *(other than by val f = m _)*
3. Are there more idiomatic ways to do what I'm trying in this example?

When I see docs for methods we see the following:

```
def m(a:Int, b:Int):Int = { a + b }
```

Looking for functions we see:

```
(a:Int, b:Int) => a + b    OR
val f:(Int,Int) => Int = (a, b) => a + b
```

However, when we poke around for `recursive functions` we nearly always see:

```
@tailrec def countStrings(a:List[String], b:Int = 0):Int = {
  if (a == Nil) b
  else countStrings(a.tail, b + 1)
}
countStrings: (a: List[String], b: Int)Int
```

So, based on all that I've read about methods the above recursive string counter is a recursive method - not a function.  Now, if we re-write this as a function according to how the docs tell us to write functions:

```
val countStrings:(List[String],Int) => Int = (a,b) => {
  if (a == Nil) b
  else countStrings(a.tail, b + 1)
}
countStrings: (List[String], Int) => Int = <function2>
```

So my question is precisely this: Is the following block annotated with `@tailrec` a function, a method, both, or something else?

```
@tailrec def countStrings(a:List[String], b:Int = 0):Int = {
  if (a == Nil) b
  else countStrings(a.tail, b + 1)
}
```

*Also, apologies if this is a duplicate, I have searched and, as with most things scala, have found conflicting opinions on this matter.  So my hope is to put forth an extremely simple example and get a definitive answer.  Thank you.*

Comment: Informally, the terms are interchangeable. Less informally, `def m` means a member that is of method type. A value `val f` may be of type `Function`, where the value might be a literal `_ => 42` or `m _` etc.

Comment: I believe answer to your final question is: it is a method. Functions are objects with `apply()` method, this is not. You can change method to a function using eta expansion and afaik there are  two ways, first is like you said `val f = m _`, other is `val f: Int => Int = m`. So basically if compiler knows he needs a function, it will be able to to expand it without your explicit underscore.

Comment: If you modify `countStrings()` so that it is no longer tail recursive, the compiler informs us: `error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated` **method** `countStrings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being precise, the example case `@tailrec def countStrings...` is a method - not a function.  While conversion to a function or writing as a function is possible the syntax in question can only properly be called a method.

Answer (score 0):

Your tailrec example is called a method in scala and tailrec annotation could be applied to a method, not to a function.

On the other hand your function implementation looks also correct achieving the same result, but you cannot annotate it to benefit from the compiler tail recursion check.

As you mentioned in your question, you can still convert your method to a function like this:

```
scala> countStrings _
res0: (List[String], Int) => Int = <function2>
```